# She was "in" or "on" the show?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

She was "in" or "on"?

Example sentences:

> She was (*in*, *on*) the drama *'Title of the drama'*.
>
> She was (*in*, *on*) the show *'Title of the show'*.

Comment: I feel like it's more natural to be "in" an one-time production (e.g. she was in *Phantom of the Opera*) and "on" a recurring production (e.g. she was on *Friends*)

Comment: My intuition is that you'd be *in* a drama or comedy but *on* a gameshow or chatshow. I don't think this is an inviolable rule; I prefer "in Friends" but "on Friends" might work too.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show how malleable and complicated English can be:

- She was in on the drama when the conman showed up at the stage door.

If you are an actor in something, it's **in:**

- She was **in** Cat on a Hot Tin Roof.
- She was **in the movie** Cat On a Hot Tin Roof.
- She was **in** several West End plays.

VERSUS"

- to be on TV
- to be on the radio

to be on tv or the radio just means that a person has been recorded in that medium.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. One is normally "in" a standalone or live show like a play or movie, but "on" a recurring recorded show like on TV.

> Hugh Jackman played the lead in *The Music Man*.
>
> Carrie Fisher was in *Star Wars*.
>
> Patrick Dempsey is an actor on *Grey's Anatomy*.

One would not typically say someone acted "on" a play or movie, although saying someone was "in" a TV show is also reasonably idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

To be on something, generally, means to be physically on top of something.

This wouldn't make sense here.

So in is more appropriate.

Comment: This doesn't follow- for instance, we say a person is "on TV" (and never \*"in TV"), yet we don't mean they're physically on top of the box!